# Solving for a Critical Point (Multivariable)

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
2x+y=&48\\
x+2y=&48\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

For a question like this we get (16, 16) but how do we solve for an answer like that. Obviously (2(16) + 16 = 48. But how do we solve to get the answer.

Comment: The same way you would solve all systems of linear equations. You can multiply the equations by a factor (for ex. $-2$) and then add the rows together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first equation we get $y=48-2x$. This gives with the second equation:

$x+2(48-2x)=48$.

Hence $x=16.$ Then we derive $y=48-2 \cdot 16=16.$

Comment: That explanation really helped, I was doing this all along but for some reason had a mental block. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Add and subtract the two equations to get

$$x+y=32,\>\>\>\>\>x-y=0$$

Comment: Thank you for showing a simpler way to do it!